# Add trailing zero to awk formatted time output

Tags: awk

I use the following command to convert a `decimal value` into a `time value`:

```
echo "1.5" | awk -F'.' '{printf $1 ":" "%.0f", $2 / 100 * 60}'
```

outputs: `1:3`

how can I make `awk` to add a trailing zero to the output so I would get: `1:30`?

Comment: What if you had a number like `24.1` (a number > 24)? Then what you would expect as result?

Comment: @αғsнιη `24.1 = 24:06` in my case I'm asking about `HH:MM` so I would have `24 hours and 6 minutes` but I see that I should edit my question to make clearer what I was taking about it is not mentioned anywhere. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Another thought: `hours=1.5; date -u -d "@$(echo "$hours * 60 * 60" | bc )" "+%H:%M"`

Comment: @glennjackman you guys are throwing at me with code :-) I don't get to edit my question, by being busy just reading and understanding the answers... THANKS! the `date` one is also a pretty nice one. Thought to just polish the output of my script and now get a complete command-line/bash tutorial :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that adding a trailing 0 is a good approach.
It may produce the intended output for the `1.5` as input,
but if you need a general solution for other inputs,
this approach will probably not work well.

A better approach is to not split the integer part and the decimal parts,
but to work with minutes, using the `/` and `%` operators to compute the correct *hours and minutes*, for example:

```
awk '{printf "%d:%02d", ($1 * 60 / 60), ($1 * 60 % 60)}' <<< 1.5
# prints 1:30

awk '{printf "%d:%02d", ($1 * 60 / 60), ($1 * 60 % 60)}' <<< 1.50
# prints 1:30

awk '{printf "%d:%02d", ($1 * 60 / 60), ($1 * 60 % 60)}' <<< 1.7
# prints 1:42

awk '{printf "%d:%02d", ($1 * 60 / 60), ($1 * 60 % 60)}' <<< 1.05
# prints 1:03
```

To handle negative values,
you can introduce an `abs` function:

```
awk 'function abs(v) {return v < 0 ? -v : v} 
     {printf "%d:%02d", ($1 * 60 / 60), ($1 * 60 % 60)}' <<< -1.7
# prints -1:42
```

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I have been looking for. I only use the command for the value being printed to the terminal to be human readable. All calculation is done before with the decimal value.

Comment: the only problem I experienced so far is that it does not work with minus values. `-1.5` would result in `-1:-30`

Comment: @nath I updated my answer to handle that

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know how many fractional digits you have, you don't know that you need to divide by 100. @janos has the correct answer, but if you insist on splitting on the decimal point, you need to force convert the fractional part back into a fractional number:

```
echo 1.5 | awk -F'.' '{printf "%d:%02d\n", $1, ("0."$2) * 60}'
```

`"0."$2` is string concatenation resulting in the string "0.5".
Then, multiply by the number 60 to get the number of minutes.

---

Or, you can figure out what divisor to use, based on the number of digits

```
awk -F'.' '{printf "%s\t%d:%02d\n", $0, $1, $2 / 10**length($2) * 60}' << END
1
1.5
1.75
1.6666667
END
```

```
1       1:00
1.5     1:30
1.75    1:45
1.6666667       1:40
```

---

But, don't do either of these things.

Comment: the advantage of this command so far seems to be the fact that it works with minus values: `-1.5` results in `-1:30`