# Awk - convert time value to decimal value

Tags: text-processing, awk, numeric-data

How can I use `awk` to convert a time value to a decimal value.

I have been using this command for the other way round [(-> from):](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/411140/240990)

```
awk '{printf "%d:%02d", ($1 * 60 / 60), ($1 * 60 % 60)}' <<< 1.5

prints: 1:30
```

how would I calculate this value `1:30` back to the decimal value `1.5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
awk -F: '{printf "%.1f", ($1*60+$2)/60}' <<< 1:30
```

Comment: no, this does not work. `1:15 -> 1.2` and `1:75 -> 2.2` etc...

Comment: OK. Perhaps I'm missing the point. Is 1:15 minutes not supposed to mean 1 minute and 15 seconds, and hence 1.2 minutes (rounded). If you wish different rounding (higher precision), you can change the .1 in the format string into a .2 or .3 etc.

Comment: oh yes, I told @steeldriver ealier, I'm missing brains :-) cheers!

Comment: works too, with using `printf "%.2f"`